# "Working on It" .issue for certain folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a folder which contains videos, mainly songs and movies and I'm not able to open it and while trying to open this folder Windows Explorer uses lots of CPU (approx. 50%) and then Explorer crashes.

[image: In this picture Explorer is stuck.]

All other folders are working fine. And certain videos (which reside in other folders and mainly downloaded from YouTube) are also taking a long time to open.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work it's possible you have error in that drive. Try the error correction tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason might be that Explorer has a problem generating icons for the videos
in this folder.

To fix, while viewing the parent folder, right click this folder,
choose *Properties*, then go to the  *Customize* tab,
and under *Optimize this folder for*, set the drop-box to
"General items" and click OK.

Comment: Thanks this worked like charm to open the folder .But the problem with playing videos still continues.Thanks again...